# Textarea (caja de comentarios) libre de scripts

Tags: php, html

¿Cómo hago para que nadie pueda introducir un script en una caja de comentarios?

Por ahora he puesto un `htmlspecialchars()` para que no se puedan meter scripts fácilmente pero, claro, con que la persona en cuestión averigüe que se pueden escribir caracteres html lo único que tiene que hacer es insertar un script con dichos caracteres.

He pensado en hacer un `preg_replace()` a los caracteres `<` y `>` pero entonces he caído en que lo único que debería hacer el usuario para saltarse ese filtro es aprovechar el tag para enlaces para meter el script dentro.

Entonces, ¿cómo lo hago para que el usuario no pueda meter de ningún modo un script dentro de la caja de comentarios?

Comment: Precisamente `htmlspecialchars()` convierte los caracteres HTML `<` y `>` en sus entidades HTML correspondientes. Lo que no entiendo es lo que dices sobre que tienes un tag de enlaces. ¿Podrías ser más específico? Si pones un ejemplo de cómo usas `htmlspecialchars()` y lo que dices de los tags de enlaces, sería suficiente.

Comment: Insisto, ¿podrías compartir el código de cómo usas `htmlspecialchars()` y la generación de enlaces? podríamos mejorar de forma segura y fiable el código. La solución que has puesto como correcta no funciona con muchas URLs (incluso las `https://` o las que no empiecen por `www.`).

Comment: Estoy votando para cerrar esta pregunta como *no está claro lo que se pregunta*, debido a que falta la información suficiente (específicamente el código para ver por qué no le funciona `htmlspecialchars()` -o al menos eso cree el autor). Sin eso, se da lugar a que no se responda correctamente, y aparezcan respuestas inseguras.

Comment: Apoyo el cierre por la falta de información y no facilitarla cuando se requiere, marcando en ese momento una respuesta de dudosa fiabilidad como "correcta" que podría llevar a que haya usuarios que lo implementen pensando que es una solución aceptada, correcta y segura.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Buenos dias, te sugiero que aproveches el preg_replace() para sustituir caracteres tipo "http", "https", "://", ".com", ".net", incluidas extensiones "html", "php", etc. y los sustituya por un espacio en blanco"", de esta manera nunca podrá insertarlos y no se activarán esas URL's. Un ejemplo:

```
    $text = " Helloooo try thiss http://www.google.com and www.youtube.com:D it works :)";
    $text = preg_replace('#http://[a-z0-9._/-]+#i', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $text);
    $regex = "#[ ]+(www.([a-z0-9._-]+))#i";
    $text = preg_replace($regex," <a href='http://$1'>$1</a>",$text);
    echo $text;
```

Comment: Haré eso gracias

Comment: Ese patrón no permite páginas `https` ni tampoco es compatible con enlaces que contengan caracteres comunes en páginas webs como el símbolo de porcentaje (usado para entidades URL como `%20` que representa un espacio en blanco) dos puntos, corchetes, interrogaciones, ampersand, almohadilla, etc.

Comment: Para más información acerca de los caracteres válidos en una URL consulta el [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2). Todos los caracteres no reservados deben dejarse sin codificar en su versión hexadecimal (`ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`), pero eso no significa que una URL con espacios en blanco convertidos en `%20` no pueda detectarse (o con tildes como https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investigaci%C3%B3n) o una que contenga un `#` (como precisamente el enlace anterior, [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2)).

Comment: ¿Para que partirse el coco con preg_replace si hay bastantes funciones que ya tratan este tema?

Comment: Estoy contigo @jonilgz, hay funciones para limpiar etiquetas html (incluso dejar las que se deseen). El problema es que no sabemos qué está haciendo ni cuales son sus requerimientos, no los ha dejado claros. Es probable que quiera tener una función que convierta URLs en enlaces, pero no está claro en la pregunta. Además, esta respuesta como tal no soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta, no entiendo por qué está marcada como solución, si no se hace un `htmlspecialchars()` a `$text` antes de los `preg_replace()` se puede meter HTML con scripts.

Comment: **Este código es completamente inseguro y presenta un alto riesgo           para quien lo use**. Como se comentó, no se debe intentar bloquear un texto específico, sino simplemente **no interpretarlo**. Al imprimir desde PHP, `htmlspecialchars()` es la única respuesta válida en este caso. Se ingrese lo que se ingrese, lo imprimirá como texto (y no como código HTML).